# Passing the updated value of a variable between modules

Tags: python, pygame

I have two modules in pygame. One (game_manager) in charge of creating the game and all the activities you can do there. Another (window_manager) in charge of updating the game window and drawing all the elements.

While refactoring the code to create new game modes I ran into a problem.

I want to pass a variable DECK_PLAYER from game_manager to window_manager:

```
# IN GAME_MANAGER.py
TABLERO = []
DECK_PLAYER = []

<some code>

def set_tablero(size):
    global TABLERO
    global DECK_PLAYER

    TABLERO = class_board.crear_tablero(size)
    DECK_PLAYER = class_cards.create_decks()

def get_deck_player():
    global DECK_PLAYER
    print("get_deck_player() -> ", DECK_PLAYER)
    return DECK_PLAYER

if __name__ == "__main__":

    board_size = 3
    CLOCK.tick(30)
    set_tablero(board_size)
    print("get_deck_player() -> ", get_deck_player())

    game_init()
```

both of the prints so far print the correct result, DECK_PLAYER as a list with elements. But if I call

```
# IN WINDOW_MANAGER.py
    deck_p = game_manager.get_deck_player()
    print(deck_p)
```

this print returns an empty list ([]), and I don't understand why. Shouldn't get_deck_player return the current value of the variable?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED IT:

as I was running game_manager as main, the call from window_manager should be:

```
import __main__

    deck_p = __main__.get_deck_player()
```

to get the correct value of the variable